# When I use the Attachment button, the attached file is saved internally, not in the filestore

Tags: odoo

If I create a document from Knowledge I can specify a directory to save into, but with the Attachment button that is not possible.

How do I get attachments to individual records to be saved externally in the filestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenERP provided a pretty good explanation on attachments storage in [this](http://help.openerp.com/question/529/where-are-document-attachments-stored/) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect.  The `Directory` field that displays in `Knowledge -> Documents -> Documents` has nothing to do with the on-disk location, and the files were indeed being saved to disk.